# How to pass metadata to "Metadata" section in "Payments" on Stripe Dashboard after a payment on Stripe Checkout?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, metadata, checkout

With the Django code below, I'm trying to pass metadata to **Metadata** section in **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard**:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect
import stripe

def test(request):
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        line_items=[
            {
                "price_data": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "unit_amount_decimal": 1000,
                    "product_data": {
                        "name": "T-shirt",
                    },
                },
                "quantity": 2,
            }
        ],
        metadata = { # Here
            "name": "Joho Smith",
            "age": "36",
            "gender": "Male",
        },
        mode='payment',
        success_url='http://localhost:8000',
        cancel_url='http://localhost:8000'
    )
    return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)
```

So, I make a payment on **Stripe Checkout** as shown below:

[image]

Then, I click on the payment on **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** as shown below:

[image]

But, **Metadata** section doesn't have anything as shown below:

[image]

But actually, **Events and logs** section has the metadata as shown below:

[image]

So, how can I pass metadata to **Metadata** section in **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** after a payment on **Stripe Checkout**?

Answer (score 1):

The metadata you're passing is being added to the Checkout Session object, not the PaymentIntent. To add these attributes to the PaymentIntent, metadata should be passed under `payment_intent_data` when creating the Checkout Session: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=python#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata

Answer (score 0):

Now, I could pass metadata to **Metadata** section in **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** after a payment on Stripe Checkout with [payment_intent_data.metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata) according to [LauraT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76316765/how-to-pass-metadata-to-metadata-section-in-payments-on-stripe-dashboard-aft#answer-76316936) as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect
import stripe

checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    line_items=[
        {
            "price_data": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "unit_amount_decimal": 1000,
                "product_data": {
                    "name": "T-shirt",
                },
            },
            "quantity": 2,
        }
    ],
    payment_intent_data={ # Here
        "metadata": {
            "name": "Joho Smith",
            "age": "36",
            "gender": "Male",
        }
    },
    mode='payment',
    success_url='http://localhost:8000',
    cancel_url='http://localhost:8000',
)
return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)
```

[image]